# I'm writing a spider base on scrapy ,I get into trouble about how to modify the scrapy.Request.formdata format, the key is dynamic

Tags: python, http, request, scrapy, form-data

```
password_name = select.xpath('//form/div/input[@type="password"]/@name').extract()[0].encode('utf-8')  
yield Request(action_url,
    meta = {'cookiejar' : response.meta['cookiejar']},
    headers = self.headers,
    formdata = {
        'mobile': 'xxxxx',
        password_name:'xxxxx', #password_name,there is wrong
        'code': self.code,
        'remember': remember,
        'backURL': backURL,
        'backTitle': backTitle,
        'tryCount': tryCount,
        'capId': capId,
        'vk': vk,
        'submit': submit
    },
    method = "POST",
    callback = self.mainInfo
)
```

**password_name is a variable and is different via every request,how can I deal with it in the formdata**

- I tried str(password_name) replace it, but failed
- I also tried dict type to replace the {...} , also failed
- how can I do with this problem??

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what is the result you get when extracting `password_name`, what information is in `formdata` and what is the expected result?

Comment: password_name is like 'password_4561','password_2343',the last four number is random via every request.  And the password_xxxx is also a part of the form_post element.